# Second derivate of integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

I am trying to derivate the following function twice:

> $\varepsilon_1(x)=\int_{x}^\infty [1+\varepsilon_1(t)](x-t)g(t)\mathrm{d}x$

for $g(t)\in C^1(x,\infty)  $.

I know that the solution has to be

> $-g(x)(1+\varepsilon_1(x))$

and I found out that the first derivate has to be

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\varepsilon_1(x)= \int_{x}^{\infty}(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$

since

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{x}^{\infty}(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\ \mathrm{d}t=-(1+\varepsilon_1(x))g(x)$

by the fundamental theorem of calculus. But how do we calculate the first derivate?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand why $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\varepsilon_1(x)= \int_{x}^{\infty}(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$ ? (it is not clear because you say "I found out that...).

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I mean that I found out that it has to be equal but I do not know why...

Answer (score 1):

Let us re-write (I assume it is a $\mathrm{d}t$, not a $\mathrm{d}x$):

$$\varepsilon_1(x)=-\int_{\infty}^x (x-t)(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

$$\varepsilon_1(x)=-\left(\int_{\infty}^x \left[x(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)-t(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\right]\mathrm{d}t \right)$$

$$\varepsilon_1(x)=-\left(\int_{\infty}^x x(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{\infty}^x t(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t \right)$$

Expanding and getting $x$ out of the first integral:

$$\varepsilon_1(x)=-x \int_{\infty}^x (1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t+\int_{\infty}^x t(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t $$

$$\varepsilon_1(x)=-x f(x)+\int_{\infty}^x t(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t \ \ \  \ \ \text{with} \ \ f(x):= \int_{\infty}^x (1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

Now we can differentiate wrt $x$, using the fundamental theorem of Calculus:

$$\tag{1}\varepsilon'_1(x)=(-1 f(x)-xf'(x)) + x(1+\varepsilon_1(x))g(x) \ \  \ \  \ \text{with} \ \ \ f'(x)= (1+\varepsilon_1(x))g(x).$$

Plugging in (1) the expressions of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$, we obtain

$$\varepsilon'_1(x)=-\int_{\infty}^x (1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\mathrm{d}t-x(1+\varepsilon_1(x))g(x) + x(1+\varepsilon_1(x))g(x) $$

A big simplification occurs, yielding the desired expression:

$$\varepsilon'_1(x)= -\int_{\infty}^x(1+\varepsilon_1(t))g(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$$

Remark: this issue could be considered as involving the derivatives of a certain convolutive product.